# Example of Monte Carlo methods on designing AIs

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, montecarlo

From what I have read in different sources, it is said that the Monte Carlo method is like getting a random sample and then testing different solutions and selecting the best solution. I don't precisely understand how this actually works in actual AI. Can you give me simple examples of it? How is it effective? Is it possible to use this in parallel with other existing algorithms specially for non-deterministic game AIs?

Comment: "Multi Armed Bandit" and "Upper Confidence Limit applied to Trees" are the google phrases to use.

Answer (score 1):

The Monte Carlo method refers to creating random numbers for simulating certain scenarios.
In itself it has nothing to do with AI.

What you are instead looking for is perhaps `Evolutionary Computing`, `Genetic Algorithms` or `Genetic Programming` where different solutions to a problem are being created and evolved using principles from biological evolution. This makes heavy use of random numbers.

For example see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm

These technologies can very well be used in parallel computing and are very suitable for non-deterministic game AIs.

Comment: Technically correct, but I believe the author meant Monte-Carlo Tree Search, which is an AI algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

when you design an AI with Monte-Carlo (MC) you do it like you would with every optimization function:

Just randomly generate solutions and choose the best one.

Example:

You have a tower defense game and do not necessarily want your enemies to always take the best way through your maze. Just generate some paths for each individual and choose the best one out of N samplings. Now your enemies will choose different, not bad, not too good ways through the maze.

You can also use a genetic algorithm for this, its an optimization algo like MC.

Evolutionary Computing or Genetic Programming are completely different things, and i would not use those to make an AI, unless you know what you are doing.

Making good AIs in games often not revolves on using the 'best' solution, but an interesting one. If you use dijkstra and all your enemies use the same path, that may be efficient, but possibly not interesting.